# How to include architecture folders [arm64-v8a , armeabi , armeabi-v7a , x86 and x86_64] in Local_LDLIBS?

Tags: android, android-ndk

How to include arm64-v8a , armeabi , armeabi-v7a , x86 and  x86_64  files in Local_LDLIBS ?

I have .a files in this 5 folders [arm64-v8a , armeabi , armeabi-v7a , x86 and  x86_64].

In my lib folder.

[image]

When I include it in my Android.mk it comes like this.

```
 clang++: error: no such file or directory: 'jni/../lib/libavformat.a'
```

My Android.mk file

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(WORKING_DIR)
LOCAL_MODULE    := a
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_AV_CONFIG_H -std=c99 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -DSTDC_HEADERS -Wno-deprecated-declarations
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := a.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lm -lz $(WORKING_DIR)/../lib/libavformat.a 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

How can I solve this ?

How can I add all architecture files in LOCAL_LDLIBS?

Comment: you can do this by the following: /lib/<your_abi>/libavformat.a e.g:  /lib/armeabi-v7a/libavformat.a.
Also you no need to include "armeabi" folder if you won't support android below 4.0 because this abi level is deprecated.

Comment: can I add like this lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libavformat.so .

Comment: i think yes you can, but if TARGET_ARCH_ABI equals to one of name of your abi folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare them as prebuilt targets in your Android.mk. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts for how to do this.